# Formula for how natural numbers n is x divisible by $2^n$ when $2^n\leq x$

Tags: number-theory, summation, logarithms, divisibility

I am currently trying to find a formula that does the same job as:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}{f(x, n)}$$ $$f(x, n)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if } x \text{ divisible by } 2^n \\[4px] 0 &\text{if } x \text{ not divisible by } 2^n \end{cases}$$
The closest I have been able to find online is tricks finding how many numbers are divisible by n which work with methods using binary however I was not able to apply it to this.

Comment: If you are satisfied with an algorithm instead of a formula, you may convert the number $x$ to a binary form and count the number $s$ of rightmost zeros (zeros after the last $1$ in the binary form). Your answer would be $s$. For example, $x=8_{10}=1000_2$, $s=3$, and $x$ divides $2^1$ and $2^2$ and $2^3$; or $x=5_{10}=101_2$, $s=0$.

Comment: I'm not clear on the exact question you want answered, so I'll put this in a comment rather than an answer. Any number $x=2^k\cdot d$ where $d$ is odd. As such, $x$ is divisible by $2^j$ for $j\le k$, and the sum you ask for is either $\sum_{i=1}^k (i)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^k (1)=k$, depending on the question you are asking.

Comment: @NikoWielopolski this works amazing, thankyou. Sadly I do need a formula so I will research on this and see if I can find a formula form of this algorithm.

Comment: It seems you are asking just for the 2-adic valuation of x: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ has a decomposition of $x=2^q\cdot m$ for some non-negative integers $q$ and $m$ where $m$ is odd, then $f(x,n)=1$ only if $n\in\{1,2,\cdots, q\}$. Also $\log_2x=q+\log_2 m$ hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\log_2 x}f(x,n)=q
$$